# weird behaviour of strstr in qt program

Tags: c++, qt, strstr

I'm a beginner, made a function which takes input from lineedit converts it into a array and then searches it to find a word. If the word is found it prints successs in a label, otherwise prints error.Problem is that it every time prints error no matter what i enter.
What am I doing wrong.

```
void MainWindow::on_consoleEdit_returnPressed()
{
    QString text = ui->consoleEdit->text();

    char enteredCmd[4096];
    strcpy(enteredCmd, "Some string data");
    text = enteredCmd;
    //enteredCmd contains all the data that text string contains
    char *open = strstr(enteredCmd, "open");

    if(open != NULL) {
        ui->answerLabel->setText("SUCCESS");
    }
    else {
        ui->answerLabel->setText("ERROR");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing same string every time, see this:

```
char enteredCmd[4096];
strcpy(enteredCmd, "Some string data");
text = enteredCmd;
```

this overrides `text` value with copy of this "Some string data" string.

Anyway you made this to complicated. `QString` have lots of functionality useful for you.

```
void MainWindow::on_consoleEdit_returnPressed()
{
    QString text = ui->consoleEdit->text();

    if(text.contains("open")) {
        ui->answerLabel->setText("SUCCESS");
    } else {
        ui->answerLabel->setText("ERROR");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is **not** searching on the text from the line edit.  Your code is actually searching for "open" on the string `enteredCmd`, which always contains "Some string data".  Thus, you should always get "ERROR" printed to your answer label.

Here's what I think you are trying to do, using `QString` instead of `strstr`:

```
void MainWindow::on_consoleEdit_returnPressed()
{
    QString text = ui->consoleEdit->text();

    if(text.contains(QStringLiteral("open"))) {
        ui->answerLabel->setText("SUCCESS");
    }
    else {
        ui->answerLabel->setText("ERROR");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you used QStringLiteral function?

Answer (score 0):

QString is designed to work with many languages so it requires some conversion to get text to a C style eight bit string. You might try something like this:

```
char *myChar = text.toLatin1().data();
```